# Json read id from multi files to show on textbox

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to show version id on listbox from multi json files but i get 
this error: No overload for method 'OpenText' takes 2 arguments, on OpenText

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\", "*.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    VersionJsonRead MCVersionsList = (VersionJsonRead)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(VersionJsonRead));
    foreach (var item in MCVersionsList.id)
    {
        if (!Regex.IsMatch((string)MCVersionsList.id, "[a-z]"))
        {
            versionsList.Items.Add((string)MCVersionsList.id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are so many hundreds of duplicates, I don't know how you didn't find the answer before asking the question. Do you even know what Google is?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Op is asking how to read multiple json files at once say file1.json and file2.json, am I missing something here  .

Answer (score 1):

`File.OpenText` is only for opening a single file. If you want to open multiple files, you can use [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and call your logic with that result:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\", "*.json");

foreach (var filePath in files)
{
    using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(filePath))
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        VersionJsonRead MCVersionsList = (VersionJsonRead)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(VersionJsonRead));
        foreach (var item in MCVersionsList.id)
        {
            if (!Regex.IsMatch((string)MCVersionsList.id, "[a-z]"))
            {
                versionsList.Items.Add((string)MCVersionsList.id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```